# NGINX redirect to proxy (proxy pass) depending on location value

Tags: nginx, server, routes, installation

Very simple idea:

I want to redirect to servers:port with following scheme:

```
requesting domain.com/9000/blabla will proxy pass to 127.0.0.1:9000
requesting domain.com/9002/asdasd will proxy pass to 127.0.0.1:9002
```

I have following rule for a single pass:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

But how to get the port from the route name as variable to the `proxy_pass` argument?

Also, please take care, I need the requested url for the passed proxies should be all after the port number from the original route, so for:

```
domain.com/9000/blabla
```

The requested url should not be `/9000/blabla` but `/blabla`.

I hope this all is possible with nginx. Thanks a lot!

CURL OUTPUT:

```
curl -v "https://dd.aa.com/9001/dada"
*   Trying XXXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dd.aa.com (XXXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=dd.aa.com
*  start date: Apr  2 08:20:16 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  1 08:20:16 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "dd.aa.com" matched cert's "dd.aa.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55b7e45d5580)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> GET /9001/dada HTTP/2
> Host: dd.aa.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 308 
< server: nginx
< date: Thu, 02 Apr 2020 11:42:17 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 303
< location: http://dd.aa.com/dada/
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-powered-by: PleskLin
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
* Connection #0 to host dd.aa.com left intact
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://dd.aa.com/dada/">http://dd.aa.com/dada/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

Comment: Do you want a static solution or a dynamic solution?

Comment: dynamic. i dont want to setup every port manually, its a range which should work. so i need it for ports 9000-9100

Comment: Try: `location ~ /(\d+/.*)$ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the port number and the URI by using a regular expression `location` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The `/` between the port number and the URI is already in the correct place, so the capture can be pasted directly into the `proxy_pass` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(\d+)(/.*)$ { 
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect http://example.com/ https://example.com/$1/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1$2$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: this works except for https://example.com/9001/poop/ ... for all others which has an item after the last slash it works, like https://example.com/9001/poop/nop. for the first example, where it does not work, nginx returns 404. even with `$is_args$args` its not working.

Comment: Check the access and error logs. It may be useful to know if the service at 9001 is redirecting the request.

Comment: `https://example.com/9001/poop/` is a 404 from nginx (not from the service server) ... but `https://example.com/9001/poop` will be redirected by the service server to https://example.com/poop what makes no sense (the service server does a 308 redirect, dont know why)

Comment: wrong, `https://example.com/9001/poop` will be redirected by nginx and then 404

Comment: Use curl to get the exact text of the Location header in the 308 response. You will need it to craft a `proxy_redirect` statement.

Comment: I have added the curl output to my question. Please help me.

Comment: I have edited my answer and split the capture into two. Hopefully I’ve got the proxy redirect correct, but they can be tricky.

Comment: Still redirect when no trailing `/` and otherwise 404 from nginx ;(

Comment: There was an error in my `proxy_redirect`, I used a `:` where a `/` should be.

Comment: yes, the redirect is fixed now. but still no data from the underlying web server on port 9001. if I request /9001/adad/ok I get the data for the request /adad/ok from my server, but when I request /9001/adad/ I get a Nginx 404 but I want to get the data for request /adad/ from my server .... why is this not working? an idea?

My underlying server registers this:
`INFO:werkzeug:172.17.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 14:20:08] "GET /freelancer-22593694 HTTP/1.0" 308 -` but does not deliver for the `freelancer-22593694` request ... why is there the redirect?